# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object (PHP-MySQL PreparedStatement)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I know this has been asked several times here but I assure you i tried every suggestion but that didn't help me. (I guess because this error is caused by a wide number of factors).

Here is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO User (Username, Password, Email, Race) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $Username, $Password, $Email, $Race);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username=?");
    if ($stmt === FALSE)
    {
        echo ($this->conn->error);
    }
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $Username);
        if($stmt -> execute())
        {
            $stmt -> bind_result($idd);
            $stmt -> fetch();
            echo $idd;
            $acre=1000;
            $alertlevel=0;
            $offperc=0;
            $deffperc=0;
            $userlevel=1;
            $upgradeavail=0;

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Info (idd, acre, alertlevel, offperc, deffperc, userlevel, upgradeavail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("iiiiiii", $idd, $acre, $alertlevel, $offperc, $deffperc, $userlevel, $upgradeavail);

            if($stmt -> execute())
            {
                echo "";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "false";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "false";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false";
    }
```

and that is my SQL table:

> Table User:  Id*(int and primary)*    Username*(varchar)*
>     Password*(varchar)*     Email*(varchar)*    Age*(int)*
>
> Table Info: IdPrimary*(int and primary)* idd*(int)*  acre*(int)* 
>   alertlevel*(int)*  offperc*(int)*  deffperc*(int)*  userlevel*(int)*
>   upgradeavail*(int)*

the one giving me the error is located on line 57 which is:

```
$stmt->bind_param("iiiiiii", $idd, $acre, $alertlevel, $offperc, $deffperc, $userlevel, $upgradeavail);
```

I used this to make sure that the select prepare is working and indeed it is.

```
if ($stmt === FALSE)
{
    echo ($this->conn->error);
}
```

this shows me that indeed it was able to fetch the Id from table User

```
  echo $idd;
```

Sorry for the long article but I wanted to give you all the possible details :)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: write `var_dump($stmt)` before the call to `bind_param` and tell us the result

Comment: the reply i got is: bool(false)

Comment: That means that the DB failed to initialize the prepared statement. Use your last error message function to see what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out you can not use the same $stmt to INSERT into two different table. so what I did is create a new $conn named $connn and it worked.
Why its not possible to INSERT into two different tables is beyond me! hope someone sheds light on this.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I didn't know that you had to create a new conn for your purposes.  If time allows, I would also try out what your code is doing with PHP PDO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm noticing spaces in your markup. I'm not sure this allowed. I've never done it myself so I can't speak with certainty.

Where you have `if($stmt -> execute())`
maybe you can try it with the spaces closed up,?

```
if($stmt->execute())
```

Comment: hmm, this seems hard to track. in the binding, are you certain that each variable being bound is indeed an integer?

Comment: Also, you have a few places where the code is echoing the word 'false' so I'd probably change each instance slightly to see where exactly the word is being echoed from

Comment: i changed the "false" echo but it still returned bool(false) due to this:     $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Info (idd, acre, alertlevel, offperc, deffperc, userlevel, upgradeavail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    echo (var_dump($stmt));
    $stmt->bind_param("iiiiiii", $idd, $acre, $alertlevel, $offperc, $deffperc, $userlevel, $upgradeavail);